# High Voltage Push-Pull MOSFET logic gates

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, 24v

[image]

Hello, I would like to implement typical MOSFET logic gates in my circuit with V+ at 24V and Input ranging from 0-24V. This posts a problem for the MOSFET however as I would either exceed the gate voltage thresholds or end up turning on both gates when the input is in between High and Low (e.g. 12V). What can I do to improve the design?

Comment: why do the gates need to be 24V? and what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Did you intend to draw the transistors as source followers rather than a typical CMOS inverter configuration? Both transistors will not be on for, say, input voltage = 12V in your circuit.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It's part of an electronic switch for IO-Link devices. IO-Link is a specification where data is transmitted at 24V.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to 'roll your own' IO-Link driver, as opposed to using a commercial solution from Maxim, TI, Linear, etc.?

Comment: some companies sell 30 volt gate drivers

Comment: Is that so? I will go have a look, thank you!